# Disjoint cycles as product of transposition

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to find the inverse of $p=(532)(164)$ to solve for $x$ an equation 
such as $p\circ  x=y.$

What I have tried is  $p=(52)(53)(14)(16)$,
 therefore            $p^{-1}=(16)(14)(53)(52)$.

Hence $p^{-1}\circ p= p \circ p^{-1} = \text{id}.$

Then going back to the equation $p\circ  x=y$, $p=(52)(53)(14)(16)$ and $y=(18753)(26)$

\begin{align*} 
\implies x&=p^{-1}y\\
&= (16)(14)(53)(52) \circ (18753)(26)\\
&=(1872)(346)\\
\end{align*}

Comment: And what direction is that? i.e. what are you trying to show?

Comment: No need to use transpositions. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* correct that $(532) = (52)(53)$ and $(164) = (14)(16)$.

So $p = (532)(164) = (52)(53)(14)(16)$.

But this implies in terms of transpositions that $p^{-1} = (16)(14)(53)(52)$ (note the reverse order!: multiply and the transpositions cancel out), 
so the final equation should change to

$$(16)(14)(53)(52)(532)(164) = \operatorname{id}$$

So $p^{-1}y = p^{-1}(18753)(26)= (16)(14)(53)(52)(18753)(26) = (1872)(346)$ indeed. 
BUt there is no need for using transpositions:

If $p = (532)(164)$ then $p^{-1} = (461)(235)$ (cycles in reverse order, order in cycles reversed), in general.

So then $p^{-1}(18753)(26) = (461)(235)(18753)(26) = (2187)(346)$, as before (recall that by definition, $(1872) = (8721) = (7218) = (2187)$ etc.)

Comment: I just check that it is equal to id... it works. I re-edited the original question. thank you.